# How to create a rest web service in informatica cloud (IICS)?

Tags: rest, web-services, informatica-cloud, iics, informatica-data-integration-hub

I couldn't create a web service in informatica cloud similar to the one we create in informatica BDM. I need to create  a web service from which I should be able to pull data from necessary schemas/Tables.

I tried using CAI in informatica cloud to do it but I can able to only pull data from an api and subsequently can store it in database but not vice versa. I need to pull data from a database using a web service or a newly created api.